# Hubble parameter change in empty universe

Tags: cosmology

[image]

According to the expression in the picture above, the Hubble parameter H(z) at time z is affected by the density distribution. In the empty universe, the density value is zero, and then the equation above is zero. How do we know the change of Hubble parameter over time in the empty universe?

In the Friedman equation, we can see that in the empty universe, the Hubble parameter is inversely proportional to the scale factor, but the relationship is not known in the above equation.

Comment: An empty universe (with no cosmological constant) is just the Minkowski geometry and isn't expanding at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in an empty universe, $H$ doesn't have to be zero because $\Omega_k$ doesn't have to be zero. An empty universe is one with

$$\Omega_\Lambda= \Omega_M =\Omega_R=0$$

but you need not assume that $\Omega_k=0$.

In fact, you can have an empty, negatively curved $(k=-1, \Omega_k>0)$, expanding universe, the so-called *Milne universe*. In this universe, it follows immediately from the Friedmann equations that

$$a(t)=\frac{t}{t_0}, \; \; H(t)=\frac 1t$$

If you assume that $k=0$, then you get a flat, static universe $(H=0,\; a(t)= const)$, which is described by the Minkowski metric (not very interesting from a cosmological point of view).

Answer (score 2):

In an empty universe ($\Omega_r = \Omega_m = 0$) that has zero cosmological constant ($\Omega_\Lambda = 0$) and no curvature ($\Omega_k = 0$), the equation you provided will give

$$
H^2 = H^2_0  (0 + 0 + 0 + 0) = 0
$$

This agrees with the Friedmann Equation given by

$$
H^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{3} \rho - \frac{kc^2}{a^2}
$$

Indeed, if the universe is empty $\rho = 0$. We also set $\Omega_k = 0$ in the equation you provided to get $H^2 = 0$, so $$\Omega_k = \frac{-k}{a^2 H^2} = 0$$ which leads to $k = 0$. Inserting into the Friedmann Equation:

$$
H^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{3} 0 - \frac{0c^2}{a^2} = 0
$$